# How to automatically append to RichTextBox in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I tried Google for an answer but didn't find what I was looking for.

I created a very simple app that lets users use a barcode scanner to scan barcodes into a text file. Everything works fine, I just want to simplify it a bit more.

Originally, I have a textbox1.text field where the scanned barcode would appear, then the user had to click the 'Add' button (Button1.Click) I placed next to the textbox field to append the barcode serial into a RichTextBox right below. Well the user found it tedious to have to click the 'Add' button every time they scanned an individual barcode.

**My Question**

Is there a way I can have the text in textbox1.text automatically append to RichTextBox as soon as a barcode is scanned? I want to eliminate having to click the 'Add' button.

Here is my current code (code for the Button1.Click button):

```
Dim scanData As String = TextBox1.Text

RichTextBox1.AppendText(scanData + " " + Format(TimeOfDay, "HH:mm:ss") + vbNewLine)

TextBox1.Clear()
TextBox1.Focus()
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, I would make sure the user cannot input text themselves by disabling the `TextBox` control (`TextBox1.Enabled=False`), then add your code to the `TextChanged` event:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Dim scanData As String = TextBox1.Text

    RichTextBox1.AppendText(scanData + " " + Format(TimeOfDay, "HH:mm:ss") + vbNewLine)

    TextBox1.Clear()
    TextBox1.Focus()
End Sub
```

Before appending to the RTB, I would check to make sure the BarCode is valid.

Comment: That worked perfect, but now it's adding a double time stamp. So instead of *SERIAL #* 2:30 PM, I'm now getting "*Serial #* 2:30 PM 2:30 PM". Any idea why? My current code is (everything under TextBox1_TextChanged): 'Dim scanData As String = TextBox1.Text

        Dim currentTime As String = TimeOfDay

        RichTextBox1.AppendText(scanData + " " + currentTime + vbLf)

        TextBox1.Focus()
        TextBox1.Clear()'

Comment: Where is the variable currentTime ?